# How to parse XML file with multi level tags and CDATA by using java?

Tags: java, xml-parsing, cdata

I want to read XML file with multi level tags and CDATA by using Java.
The sample XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Result>
  <ResultDetails>
  <SearchFilmResult ItemType="film">
 <FilmDetails>
    <FilmDetail>
       <Film Code="INCEPTION"><![CDATA[INCEPTION 2010]]></Film>
       <Imdb>8.8</Imdb>
       <FilmInformation>
            <Director><![CDATA[Christopher Nolan]]></Director> 
            <Actors>
                <Actor1><![CDATA[Leonardo DiCaprio]]></Actor1>
                <Actor2><![CDATA[Joseph Gordon-Levitt]]></Actor2>
                <Actor3><![CDATA[Ellen Page]]></Actor3>
            </Actors>  
       </FilmInformation>
    </FilmDetail>
   </FilmDetails>
  </SearchFilmResult>
  </ResultDetails>
</Result>
```

The expected result is:

> Film Code = INCEPTION
>
> Film Name = INCEPTION 2010
>
> IMDB = 8.8
>
> Director = Christopher Nolan
>
> Actors = Leonardo DiCaprio, Joseph Gordon-Levitt, Joseph Gordon-Levitt

Does anyone can guide me how to do? Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried searching? There are numerous ways to parse Xml with Java. What are the problems you've found so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at XPath?

Here's a very simple example that will parse this sample XML, but I'd think it would be up to you to explore the possibilities that are out there and determine what will work well for you.

Give this a try:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // sample xml
        String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
                "<Result>\n" +
                "  <ResultDetails>\n" +
                "  <SearchFilmResult ItemType=\"film\">\n" +
                " <FilmDetails>\n" +
                "    <FilmDetail>\n" +
                "       <Film Code=\"INCEPTION\"><![CDATA[INCEPTION 2010]]></Film>\n" +
                "       <Imdb>8.8</Imdb>\n" +
                "       <FilmInformation>\n" +
                "            <Director><![CDATA[Christopher Nolan]]></Director> \n" +
                "            <Actors>\n" +
                "                <Actor1><![CDATA[Leonardo DiCaprio]]></Actor1>\n" +
                "                <Actor2><![CDATA[Joseph Gordon-Levitt]]></Actor2>\n" +
                "                <Actor3><![CDATA[Ellen Page]]></Actor3>\n" +
                "            </Actors>  \n" +
                "       </FilmInformation>\n" +
                "    </FilmDetail>\n" +
                "   </FilmDetails>\n" +
                "  </SearchFilmResult>\n" +
                "  </ResultDetails>\n" +
                "</Result>";

        // read the xml
        InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));

        // build a document model
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = db.parse(source);

        // create an xpath interpreter
        XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

        // evaluate nodes
        String filmCode = xpath.evaluate("Result/ResultDetails/SearchFilmResult/FilmDetails/FilmDetail/Film/@Code", document);
        String filmName = xpath.evaluate("Result/ResultDetails/SearchFilmResult/FilmDetails/FilmDetail/Film", document);
        String imdb = xpath.evaluate("Result/ResultDetails/SearchFilmResult/FilmDetails/FilmDetail/Imdb", document);
        String director = xpath.evaluate("Result/ResultDetails/SearchFilmResult/FilmDetails/FilmDetail/FilmInformation/Director", document);

        // get actor data
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("Result/ResultDetails/SearchFilmResult/FilmDetails/FilmDetail/FilmInformation/Actors/child::*");
        NodeList actors = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // compile actor list
        for ( int i = 0; i < actors.getLength(); i++ ) {
            String actorName = actors.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
            if ( i > 0 ) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
            sb.append(actorName);
        }

        // print output
        System.out.println("Film Code = " + filmCode);
        System.out.println("Film Name = " + filmName);
        System.out.println("IMDB = " + imdb);
        System.out.println("Director = " + director);
        System.out.println("Actors = " + sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Film Code = INCEPTION
Film Name = INCEPTION 2010
IMDB = 8.8
Director = Christopher Nolan
Actors = Leonardo DiCaprio, Joseph Gordon-Levitt, Ellen Page
```